# Nginx as image proxy is slow with queuing time (chrome network tool) very high

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

As you can see in the picture below, the queueing time and TTFB is very high compare with the rest.

My website has many images, approx over 100 images but they all are rather small (less than 100KB)

I'm using nginx as reverse proxy like below. Is there anyway I can fix this?

```
location /mypath {
    proxy_cache backcache;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$document_uri$is_args$arg_key";
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_valid 30d; # 30d
    proxy_cache_valid any 15s; # 15s everything else
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;

    proxy_pass http://myproxyurl.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

[image: chrome network]

Comment: Maybe your `myproxyurl.com` is slow?

Comment: @AlexeyTen i checked. If i didn't proxy, it's fast again.

Comment: Check nginx's error.log. Also look at `$upstream_response_time`